# socket.io doesn't send to all room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am using Socket.io with react to do a chat room, when a new user join the room i want to send an update to all clients.

```
const updateDiscussionClients = room => {
    let currentClients = RoomClients({room, io, connections})
    console.log(currentClients); // printing correct data
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room));
    socket.to(room).emit('clients_discussion', currentClients)
}

socket.on("join_discussion", (data) => {
    let room = 'room_' + data.id + data.name
    socket.join(room)
    updateDiscussionClients(room)
   
})
```

everything is working fine but the message received by old client, without the last one who

output of the logs:

```
[
  { name: 'Mohamad Zbib', id: '202100006' },
  { name: 'pu10', id: '10' }
]
Set(2) { 'pbKuaEdrfg7n83YyAAAD', '3QYOJCzlxxMOLquzAAAB' }
```

the event is received by `pbKuaEdrfg7n83YyAAAD`, but `3QYOJCzlxxMOLquzAAAB` didn't receive it , he will receive if an update happened later

Comment: can you provide more details? it seems like maybe you submitted your questiojn without fully finishing your thought

Comment: i just edited a little bit, i don't think that there's a missing details,  i did some search but i didn't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is *3QYOJCzlxxMOLquzAAAB* sender of that event, which will not receive?

`socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);` will send to all in room except sender.
`io.in("room1").emit(/* ... */);` will send to all in room

Check this [cheat sheet](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/) for more info

Comment: yes he is the sender, but i tried `to` and `in` and both are the same, the sender didn't recieve

Comment: i just forget the difference between `io` and `socket` after using `in`